# SED: Appending extra bytes after a specific byte position

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to **append** X bytes after Y bytes in a binary file using bash.

Using the below code seems to work fine but it fails (there is a shift) when encountering xFF

Example: To append 1 byte (xaa) after 907 bytes

```
sed -r -i 's/^.{907}/&"\xaa"/' file.txt
```

Output (when ok):

```
cat file.txt | od -t x1 -t c -Ad
```

[image: OK output]

Output (when not ok):

```
sed -r -i 's/^.{907}/&"\xaa"/' file_2.txt
cat file_2.txt | od -t x1 -t c -Ad
```

[image: NOT ok - Shift in the output]

Any idea why this happens and if there are alternatives for the SED being used?

Comment: `sed` is used specifically with text file input, not binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a very good idea to edit binary stream with sed, in my opinion.
Usually you convert the binary stream in a hex dump, edit it
and convert it back.

Like that:

```
$ hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2X"' file1 \
| sed -r 's/^.{1814}/&aa/' \
| xxd -r -p > file2
```

You can also use Perl instead of `xxd`:

```
| perl -e 'print pack "H*", <STDIN>'
```

Comment: +1, `sed` is for text editing. You could use `xxd` for the binary->ascii conversion as well, e.g.: `xxd -p file1 | tr -d '\n'`

Comment: Is there an xxd alternative to convert back? Seems it is not installed on our redhat server. On my VM it works without problems and gives the needed output! +1

Comment: @Igor: Works fine with perl on the server! Thanks !

Comment: @Danjel: I am glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned elsewhere `sed` only supports text files. I think the most convenient tool for the job is `bbe` ([Binary Block Editor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bbe-/)), which works very similarly to `sed` but on binary data.

You start by defining the block you want to edit with the `-b` switch, `-b 907:1` in your case, see pages 3 and 4 in [the manual](http://bbe-.sourceforge.net/bbe.pdf) for more options. Now tell `bbe` what commands to run on the block with the `-e` switch, `A \xaa` in your case, see pages 5-8 in [the manual](http://bbe-.sourceforge.net/bbe.pdf) for more commands.

Taken together:

```
bbe -b 907:1 -e 'A \xaa' file.txt > modified_file.txt
```

Another example using the whole file as a block:

```
bbe -e 'i 907 \xaa' file.txt > modified_file.txt
```

Comment: Tried it out today and confirm it works fine too. Thanks again.

Comment: @Danjel: If your question is solved, remember to [accept the best answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).